# JS / Jquery - Redirect to .php site on background every X sec

Tags: php, jquery

I found out a way how to enter things to database using PHP and JQUERY, it works for me correctly (code below) but as soon as i am completly new in JQUERY and i'm looking for some aditional staf I come here for advise, how can i automaticy call this redirect to PHP file for example every 10 sec to force save changes.

```
<form name="form1" action="">
Enter Name <input type="text" name="t1" id="t1"></td> <br>
Enter City <input type="text" name="t2" id="t2"></td> <br>
<input type="button" name="button1" value="Insert to DB" onClick="aa()">
</form>
<div id="d1"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function aa()
{
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "insert.php?name=" + document.getElementById("t1").value + "&city=" + document.getElementById("t2").value, false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);

    document.getElementById("d1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;;
}
</script>
```

Thank you guys.

Comment: Why do you need this? Automatically inserting something in to a database every 10 seconds seems a little wasteful in terms of network traffic and database size.

Comment: Doesn't `setInterval` do what you need?

Comment: Right atleast i need to know how to call it automatilcly no matter on what user do, after that i edit it for my personal useage. Like i want to make a list of things, somehing like "To Do list" and if user click on checkbox i want it to automaticly redirect

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Have you ever used Google Docs? It performs auto-save every few seconds.

Comment: Does it make more sense to look for change events on your inputs and auto-save after every change? You also should url encode the values you are concatenating into your parameter string (or better yet, use jQuery `serialize()`. Not sure if you are really using jQuery though.  You tagged this question with it, but your code example is not using jQuery for ajax functionality (which probably doesn't make sense).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
function aa() { // code here };
var timer = setInterval(aa, 1000*10); // every 10 seconds
```

Here is some further information https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval

But make sure on the server side that you parse the result to prevent SQL injections, if you use a relational database.

Edit: update to seconds